# "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid" Using firebase

Tags: firebase, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Firebase tells me to do this:

[image]

So I did
[image]

But I'm still getting this error "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid"

I feel like I've followed instructions exactly but it's still not working. I have no idea how to debug this further. Any suggestions?

Here is my frontend code where I call `signIn`

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
  provider.addScope("Calendars.Read");
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(handleResponse);
```

**Edit**
I changed the url to my custom domain and it seemed to be working but now I'm getting `Error getting verification code from microsoft.com response: proof key for code exchange is required for cross-origin`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Firebase decided to change the url where it handled auth. Instead of using the `.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` url, it is using my actual custom domain. Though I don't really understand why this would happen...?

The `Error getting verification code from microsoft.com response: proof key for code exchange is required for cross-origin` was happening because I had configured an SPA on Azure instead of a Web platform.

Answer (score 0):

@dallin-davis is right, instead of
`https://[projectname].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`

I had to add my domain url under "Web" section.
`https://mydomain/__/auth/handler`

[image]